# InMemorySigner from node crypto key

Tags: taquito

Is it possible to generate keys with node's `crypto` library and import them in the `InMemorySigner`?

I want to generate keys that I can use to sign transactions for a proof of concept.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this with a node, but we have a tiny typescript library to do this:

https://gitlab.com/functori/dev/funkey.ts

Comment: I think Ulrik means the node.js crypto modules for cryptographic functionality?

Comment: Typescript or Node.Js is (almost) the same. And he wants to generate keypairs to sign ops with :-)

Comment: I posted a solution that I found in the end so it is possible! :)

Answer (score 3):

So what I did in the end is something like this:

```
// Signer factory example from the docs 
const signerFactory = async (rpcUrl, pk) => {
  const Tezos = new Taquito.TezosToolkit(rpcUrl);
  await Tezos.setProvider({
    signer: await Signer.InMemorySigner.fromSecretKey(pk),
  });
  return Tezos;
};

// Hashing function to hash the key
const toB58Hash = (payload, prefix) => {
  const blakeHash = blake.blake2b(payload, undefined, 32);
  const tmp = new Uint8Array(prefix.length + blakeHash.length);
  tmp.set(prefix);
  tmp.set(blakeHash, prefix.length);
  const b58 = bs58check.encode(Buffer.from(tmp));
  return b58;
};

export const get_signer = async () => {
  // Generate a key pair
  const key_pair = crypto.generateKeyPair("ed25519");
  // Export in pem format
  const pem = key_pair.privateKey.export({
    type: "pkcs8",
    format: "pem",
  });

  // Take the actual key part from the pem formatted string
  // and encode it with the b58 function above
  const rawPrivateKey = pem.split("-----")[2].trim();
  const encodedKey = toB58Hash(rawPrivateKey, prefix.edsk2);

  const signer = await signerFactory(
    "https://mainnet.tezos.marigold.dev",
    encodedKey
  );
};
```

Note that this should most likely not be used in a production environment with a bunch of money.